# Copying apk's from phone to tablet

Tags: tablet, apk, non-market

I have a Marketless tablet (Coby Kyros), and I bought a Samsung Captivate (AT&T).

Will I be able to copy the apk's I download from the phone into the tablet?

Comment: Note: some apps may not work if they require Google licensing

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Dropbox to transfer the apks.  That was how I got them on my Archos tab before I got the market on there.  Dropbox lets you download the dropbox app directly from their website, so there's no market needed.  After that all you have to do is send every apk from your phone that you want onto your tablet to Dropbox, then you can install them directly from there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- the easiest method is to put them on the SD card, use a file manager to browse to them, and click each to get the installation prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If they were free applications, then you will be able to copy them over easily. If they are *paid* applications, you will need to go to Market>(Menu Button)>My Apps to download them. Good thing they're bound to the Google account! Of course, this hinges on whether you get a tablet that *has* market. I think the Archos tablets and similar devices did not have it, but the Honeycomb tablets do.